# Subset data after multiple condition

Tags: r, subset

I have two dataframes named as User and Master

```
User = read.csv(text = "
Ticket,Vehicle,Created
A,7164,1/1/2017
B,7163,1/2/2017
C,7162,26/1/2017", header = TRUE) 

Master = read.csv(text = "
Ticket,Vehicle,Created
E,7164,29/12/2016
F,7163,26/12/2017
G,7164,31/1/2017
R,7164,02/02/2017
H,7162,28/1/2017", header = TRUE)
```

I want that in `User` dataframe I would like to append the column `Ticket` for vehicles that match with the vehicle number for every `i` value and also after the created date for `i` value.

```
Ex:  
**Output**  

Ticket Vehicle Created      Ticket.1    Ticket.2    
A        7164    1/1/2017    G             R
B        7163    1/2/2017    NA  
C        7162    26/1/2017   H
```

So for Vehicle 7164 two entries are there in `Master` but only one is after 1/1/2017 and that is G.

I tried the following code

```
dfagg <- aggregate(Ticket ~ Vehicle + Created, Master, function(i) tail(i))
dfwide <- reshape(dfagg, timevar='Ticket', idvar=c('Vehicle'), direction="wide")
names(dfwide) <- gsub("Vehicle", "Ticket", names(dfwide))
```

However I do not get the result after the created date of the vehicle that matches my result

Comment: Please use the tools to properly format the code/data chunks.

Comment: You should give your data in a reproducible manner. Look up how to do so. Makes it easier to help out.

Answer (score 2):

*NB: I suppose that the date for F is 26/12/2016 (not 26/12/2017), otherwise your output is wrong.*

One way to achieve that is to use the `sqldf` package.

First, convert your dates from character to date:

```
User$Created = as.Date(User$Created, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
Master$Created = as.Date(Master$Created, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then join:

```
library(sqldf)

Output <- sqldf("select u.Ticket, u.Vehicle, u.Created, 
                        m.Ticket as Master_Ticket
                from User u left join Master m 
                  on (u.Vehicle = m.Vehicle and u.Created < m.Created)")

Output
#   Ticket Vehicle    Created Master_Ticket
# 1      A    7164 2017-01-01             G
# 2      A    7164 2017-01-01             R
# 3      B    7163 2017-02-01          <NA>
# 4      C    7162 2017-01-26             H
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to have only one row per user ticket, one way is to aggregate:

```
Output2 <- sqldf("select u.Ticket, u.Vehicle, u.Created,
                         group_concat(m.Ticket, ' ') as Master_Tickets
                 from User u left join Master m 
                   on (u.Vehicle = m.Vehicle and u.Created < m.Created)
                 group by u.Ticket, u.Vehicle, u.Created")

Output2
#   Ticket Vehicle    Created Master_Tickets
# 1      A    7164 2017-01-01            G R
# 2      B    7163 2017-02-01           <NA>
# 3      C    7162 2017-01-26              H
```

And if for some reason you absolutely need to have one column for each match:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

Output3 = Output %>%
  group_by(Ticket) %>%
  mutate(column_name = paste0('Ticket.', row_number())) %>%
  dcast(Ticket + Vehicle + Created ~ column_name, value.var = "Master_Ticket")

Output3
#   Ticket Vehicle    Created Ticket.1 Ticket.2
# 1      A    7164 2017-01-01        G        R
# 2      B    7163 2017-02-01     <NA>     <NA>
# 3      C    7162 2017-01-26        H     <NA>
```

Comment: If the ticket A has two matches then two rows are getting created, I want the answers in two separate columns is that possible                                Ex Output  
#   Ticket Vehicle    Created Ticket.1     Ticket.2  
# 1      A    7164 2017-01-01      G           R  
# 2      B    7163 2017-02-01   <NA>          # 3      C    7162 2017-01-26      H

Comment: @Ashish Ok, are there two matches max for each row?

Comment: @scrabee There can be any number of matches ,2 is not a concrete answer..it can have n matches..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution including the data correction for F noted by @Scarabee. `lubridate` is used for date conversion. `dplyr::rename()` can be added to get more meaningful column names.

```
library(lubridate)
User = read.csv(text = "
Ticket,Vehicle,Created
A,7164,1/1/2017
B,7163,1/2/2017
C,7162,26/1/2017", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
User$Created <- dmy(User$Created)

Master = read.csv(text = "
Ticket,Vehicle,Created
E,7164,29/12/2016
F,7163,26/12/2016
G,7164,31/1/2017
H,7162,28/1/2017", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
Master$Created <- dmy(Master$Created)

library(dplyr)
User %>% 
  left_join(Master, by="Vehicle") %>% # left takes every row from Master
  mutate(Ticket_y = ifelse(Created.x < Created.y, # apply date restriction
                           Ticket.y, NA)) %>%
  group_by(Ticket.x) %>%          # group by User ticket      
  arrange(desc(Ticket.y)) %>%     # push NA values to end
  filter(row_number() == 1 ) %>%  # keep only first row withing group
  ungroup() %>%                   # remove grouping
  select(Ticket.x, Created.x, Ticket_y) %>% # keep columns of interest
  arrange(Ticket.x)  # sort

      Ticket.x  Created.x Ticket_y
         <chr>     <date>    <chr>
# 
#   1        A 2017-01-01        G
#   2        B 2017-02-01     <NA>
#   3        C 2017-01-26        H
```

Comment: Nice answer. FWIW I think `slice(1)` is more compact and maybe easier to read than `filter(row_number() == 1)`.